# First simple if statement in Qt: Comparison of two chars

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have problems with my first Qt Program (should be a simple calculator). I would like to calculate everytime when there is already an operator in my calculator display (lineEditDisplay) and i press an operator again.
My Problem is that he recognize a '+' but not a '-' or '*' and i don't know why.

For example if i press 4, then -, then 2, the display shows me 4-2, but now if i press the posted + button i get displayed 6+ insead of 2+. So it seams that it goes in the first if statement and calculate firstNumber+secondNumber.

Here is the clicked slot for the addition button:

```
void Calculator::on_pushButtonAddition_clicked()
{
    QString inLineEditDisplay=ui->lineEditDisplay->text(); //Get whats in display
    //Loop through display string
    for(int i=0; i<inLineEditDisplay.length(); i++)
    {
        //Check if there is already a operator -> if yes then calculate first so
        //we can add a new operator; first check for +
        if(inLineEditDisplay[i]=='+')
        {
            //Get the two numbers; in front of and behind the operator
            QString firstPart=inLineEditDisplay.left(i);
            QString secondPart=inLineEditDisplay.right(inLineEditDisplay.length()-i);
            //Change from QString to int, so we can calculate with
            int firstPartAsInt=firstPart.toInt();
            int secondPartAsInt=secondPart.toInt();
            inLineEditDisplay=QString::number(firstPartAsInt+secondPartAsInt);
        }
        //Now check for -
        if(inLineEditDisplay[i]=='-')
        {
            //Get the two numbers; in front of and behind the operator
            QString firstPart=inLineEditDisplay.left(i);
            QString secondPart=inLineEditDisplay.right(inLineEditDisplay.length()-i);
            //Change from QString to int, so we can calculate with
            int firstPartAsInt=firstPart.toInt();
            int secondPartAsInt=secondPart.toInt();
            inLineEditDisplay=QString::number(firstPartAsInt-secondPartAsInt);
        }
        //Now check for *
        if(inLineEditDisplay[i]=='*')
        {
            //Get the two numbers; in front of and behind the operator
            QString firstPart=inLineEditDisplay.left(i);
            QString secondPart=inLineEditDisplay.right(inLineEditDisplay.length()-i);
            //Change from QString to int, so we can calculate with
            int firstPartAsInt=firstPart.toInt();
            int secondPartAsInt=secondPart.toInt();
            inLineEditDisplay=QString::number(firstPartAsInt*secondPartAsInt);
        }
        //Now check for /
        if(inLineEditDisplay[i]=='/')
        {
            //Get the two numbers; in front of and behind the operator
            QString firstPart=inLineEditDisplay.left(i);
            QString secondPart=inLineEditDisplay.right(inLineEditDisplay.length()-i);
            //Change from QString to int, so we can calculate with
            int firstPartAsInt=firstPart.toInt();
            int secondPartAsInt=secondPart.toInt();
            inLineEditDisplay=QString::number(firstPartAsInt/secondPartAsInt);
        }
    }
    inLineEditDisplay.append('+');
    ui->lineEditDisplay->setText(inLineEditDisplay);
}
```

I tested it also with

```
if(inLineEditDisplay[i]==QLatin1Char('+'))
```

but that didn't change anything (can't see any different behaviour)

@https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422324/user2422324

calculator.cpp -> http://pastebin.com/1bsUgg3Y

calculator.h -> http://pastebin.com/F0kbkx4g

main.cpp -> http://pastebin.com/keCu6Gcr

calculator.ui -> http://pastebin.com/nTEauYAH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a stupid one...

`QString.length()` returns the number of elements and i loop over `i=0; i<QString.length; i++;` till i i found an operator.

Now the left side of the operator is `QString[0;i[` or `QString.left(i)` and the right side (where the error was) `QString]i; QString.length()]` or `QString.right(QString.length()-(i+1))` and not `QString.length().right.length()-i`

Answer (score 0):

The function `Calculator::on_pushButtonAddition_clicked()` is only be called if the `+` button is triggered. Are you sure you linked this function to all the other operator buttons?

There should be functions **like** (I dont know whether they are called exactly like that)

`Calculator::on_pushButtonSubtraction_clicked()` `Calculator::on_pushButtonDivision_clicked()` `Calculator::on_pushButtonMultiplication_clicked()`

Comment: Yes every button has the same content. Only that i append an other operator. The appending is working but it's always calculating with +.

Comment: I still guess the fault is that there is something wrong linking the operator buttons with the functions. Could you post the code that triggers the `on_pushButton......_clicked()` functions?